# IOS AIR app still running when the iphone is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I just made a simple game with `flash professional 6.0` and the `adobe AIR 4.4` SDK for iPhone.

The problem is that when I lock the iphone pressing the power button, the screen switches off as usual, but the music of the game still sounds. If I exit the game pressing the home button it exits fine. Is only when locking the phone with the app opened.

Comment: What iPhone are you using (5S, 5C, 4S, etc)? And is it jailbroken? It may have something to do with a software/hardware issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add listeners for the events `Event.DEACTIVATE` on your main class and `Event.EXITING` on `NativeApplication.nativeApplication`.

On the events handlers you can do what you want to stop / pause your game.

Add a listener to the event `Event.ACTIVATE` on the main class to resume the game.