# AS3 (iOS Adove Air) Still play sound when locked/on another app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am making a app that plays a .mp3 file (It has different music on that one .mp3 that uses a URL) and I'm having a problem, when you close the app on iPad, iPhone, etc it stops playing that .mp3 file, how do you make it where it keeps going until you fully close the app or pause the sound inside the app using AS3?

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22370037/1206613

Comment: That isn't what I meant, I want it to play the sound even when locked/off the app.